# Difference between write vs add

Tags: dart

I'm not clear about the differences between socket.write vs socket.add

I observed both are different but not sure how it is different and what are the differences.

Please clarify

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add(List<int> data)` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/IOSink/add.html takes a list of `int` and sends them as byte data,

while `write(Object obj)` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/IOSink/write.html accepts any value that it converts to a string (calls `.toString()` on the passed value) and sends the resulting string.